# What are the effects of ramming with tanks and how to do it effectively?

Tags: company-of-heroes-2

I normally play German but I am encountering an increasing number of Russian players who get T-34's and ram my tanks with theirs or roll over my sniper before I can move them.  It is the worst when my tanks are rammed because it breaks my main gun and my engine.

When I decided to go Russian and try tank ramming tactics I found it is actually difficult and the few times I was able to hit German tanks their main gun didn't break.

Does ramming effects depend on the type of panzer you ram or the distance you tank drives prior to ramming? If so how can one effectively disable the main gun on a panzer with ramming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the chance to break the main gun changes based on which tank does the ramming.  The T-34, for instance, has close to a 100% chance to break the main gun of any other tank it rams.  They takes out their own main gun in the process as well, so don't rely on only it.

Generally, though, since no tank has a guarantee of disabling their main gun, it's better used as a last ditch effort to take another tank with the rammer.  If you're lucky, you'll take out their main gun or other component, and that means that unit is disadvantaged until it can be repaired.  If you get lucky and take out their main gun, it's essentially target practice.

For the T-34s, though, since they can be built relatively cheaply, they can be used at the start of a skirmish to take out heavier tanks, and automatically turn the fight into your favor.  You'll probably lose the tank in the process, but disabling a Tiger or Panther for the cost of a T-34 is pretty heavily weighted in your favor.  Follow up with some AT infantry, or other tank destroyers, and that tank won't be making it home.